# Git: find local branch used to push to origin

Tags: git

New to git.

I am in a situation where I have a bunch of local branches and I want to track down the one I was working on to push up changes to the origin.

What git command can I use?

I did git log origin/branch7 and that returned a whole bunch of commits.

in particular this one:

```
commit 5473e16761f4074a69321b671f88e6a66103c41f
Author: Me
Date:   Mon Jan 13 12:17:26 2014 +1100

    Encapsulate static inner class. Formatted code.
```

How can I use the commit ID to track down which local branch I used to push up those changes?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here... When you do `git log` and see your commits, they are pushed to the same branch... You can't push from one branch to another... So very confused by what you mean exactly.

Comment: @MMM: you can push from anything to anything, it just takes extra work. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
git branch --contains <commit id>
```

in your case

```
git branch --contains 5473e16761f4074a69321b671f88e6a66103c41f
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio! When I ran that particular commit it returned nothing which was weird. But then I ran it with a commit ID before the one I specified and it tracked it down. This command is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Did some reading [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch.html) and ran:

```
git show-branch
```

and that listed all the commits I made for all of my local branches. This enabled me to track down which local branch I was working on for that particular commit.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately there's no guaranteed answer to the question.  The problem comes down to the fact that it's possible to push *from* any commit-ID, *to* any write-able name on any remote you can write on:

```
git push +1234567:origin/bluebranch
```

Assuming you have a commit whose ID can be abbreviated `1234567`, this connects to the remote named `origin` and asks it to force-update its idea of branch `bluebranch` to be commit `1234567` (well, whatever the full SHA-1 is for that local commit-ID).  That commit need not be the tip of a branch at all, in your own repo; it just has to exist.

(The remote has the right to refuse an update, even with the `+` or `--force` flag.  But that's a different thing entirely.)

The best you can do is look at which branches are either set to, or contain, the commit identified on the remote.  Note that a branch name simply indicates which commit in a graph of commits should be consider to be the "tip" of that branch:

```
        D--E  <-- branch1
       /
A--B--C       <-- branch2
    \
     F        <-- branch3
```

Here, commit `B` is present on all three branches, but is the "tip" of `branch2` even though it's fairly far back on `branch1` and one step back on `branch3`.

Using `git branch --contains` (as in [Sergio Aristizábal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21174454/1256452)) you can find that commit `B` is contained within all three branches.  Looking at `git show-ref` you can see what the tips of all branches are and compare raw IDs, to see if the remote's idea of the branch matches your own.  However, if someone else has added commits and you have picked those up in your repo, but not on your local branch references, they won't necessarily match.

---

The most general rule is that you should not care *how* some remote got into the state it is now in, you should only care about what *you* want to have happen to it next.  You just run `git fetch` to synchronize with "the state it is now in", then poke around to see the state, and choose what to do with your local branches (if any) to synchronize them with the remote (if desired), perhaps transplanting (rebasing) old commits and/or adding new commits (if/as desired).

Of course, people being people, getting branch names right works wonders for aiding one's memory. :-)

---

Here's some useful tips for "getting branch names right":

- If possible, use the same name in your local repo as on the remote repo.

  It's really confusing when your local branch is named `cool-hack` but the remote branch is named `tonka` as a development code name.
- Use a name that means something to all the people who will work on it.

  Code name tonka is great if that actually means something to everyone.  Otherwise it's just baffling.  You might as well call it `cool-hack`.
- Use `git config` to set `push.default` to `simple` or `upstream`: this means that running `git push` with no options will attempt to push the local branch, whatever its name is, to its default upstream.  With `simple`, this will refuse unless that branch really does have the same name.  That is, if local branch `tonka` is "tracking" `origin/tonka`, and the current branch you're on right now is `tonka`, then `git push` (with no other arguments) will ask `origin` to update *its* `tonka` to match yours.  But if local branch `cool-hack` is tracking `origin/tonka` and you're on `cool-hack`, the push will fail unless you're using the `upstream` setting.
- Therefore, try to use local tracking branches, so that you can just `git push` (and also `git fetch` followed by `git rebase` or `git merge`) with no extra typing required.  Moreover `git branch -vv` will tell you the name of the remote branch.